# Retrieve BCC/BCH but now have 0. Was i Hacked?

Tags: electrum, blockchain-fork, bitcoin-cash, hack

hey guys i followed an instruction from reddit and exodus chat and both had similar instructions to retieve Bitcoin Cash. I followed the instructions and it seemed like i received the coins though it took hours to confirm.

I started by stransfering my BTC from Exodus to Jaxx, then use the Exodus private key to retrieve BCC with Electron Cash.

I opened it yesterday and it said i had the balance i expected. today i open it it says 0 BCC.

take a look:
[image]

I havnt sent any of my BCC to anyone. I was trying to send to my exchange when the app said "insufficient funds". Was i hacked or something?

Help!

Comment: I believe Electron/um can't distinguish BCC from BTC transactions, so if you spent coins in one side, it will show up as an unconfirmed tx on the other side.

Comment: what do i do then? BCC is falling and i need to cash out quick!!! @PieterWuille

Comment: DO you have a link to instructions on how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not the only one who ran into this. Someone posted about this on [bitcoin talk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2059091.0) too. One user posted this is the result of a peer list poisoning bug:

> Electron Cash has a "peer list poisoning" bug, see
>   https://twitter.com/ElectrumWallet/status/892433256385261568 This is
>   probably what you are experiencing. To fix that, disable auto-connect,
>   and select a server that you trust to be a BCC server.

Apparently the casharia server is working for people.

Also quick PSA that Electron Cash is not related to the Electrum Bitcoin SPV wallet. This is the announcement on BCC from Elecrum: https://electrum.org/bcc.txt

There's also a [warning](https://electrum.org/bcc2.txt) about Electron Cash from Electrum:

> The person who distributes the Electron Cash binaries has decided to
>   remain anonymous, and uses the fake name "Jonald Fyookball" in order
>   to sign Electron Cash binaries. Thus, if these binaries contain code
>   that is designed to steal your bitcoins, the author of the theft will
>   be anonymous and walk away safely with your funds.

Comment: which wallet do you recommend me using?

Comment: [Trezor](https://blog.trezor.io/claim-bcash-bitcoin-cash-bch-bcc-trezor-wallet-f0a810d5864a) and [Ledger](http://support.ledgerwallet.com/knowledge_base/topics/select-bitcoin-cash-blockchain-main-or-split) both support BCH splitting. That's probably the safest bet at the moment. Bitcoin magazine also has an [article on supporting wallets and exchanges](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/these-bitcoin-exchanges-and-wallets-are-supporting-bitcoin-cash/).

Comment: I'm unable to get a hardware wallet at this moment. I need to the the coins and sell immediately since the price is dropping rapidly. I'll check out the article and see recommendations. Rhabks