# How safe is Nicolas Dorier's BCCSpliter?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain-fork, bitcoin-cash

I noticed a link to this resource on an article talking about safely splitting your BTC and BCH(/BCC):

https://github.com/NicolasDorier/BCCSpliter

Has anyone reviewed the source code and is it safe to use?  Could someone provide a run-down on how it works?  I read the readme but am hoping for a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

The readme file pretty much explains everything step by step.

But if you don't have much technical knowledge, the best one to use will be a wallet with some GUI. I suggest you to use [Electron Cash](http://electroncash.org/).

But before using your private key of the BTC addresses, move those BTC to any other addresses, and then only use the private keys in this software (just a precaution).

You can also import multiple private keys together in this software.

P.S. I cannot comment due to the reputation limit right now, hope this helps you somehow.

Edit: Use precaution while using Electron Cash, as it is as of writing this answer is not much tested and have bugs.

Comment: Take a look at the warnings surrounding electron cash before you trust it, for example in the answer here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57545/retrieve-bcc-bch-but-now-have-0-was-i-hacked

Comment: I have done some transaction using electron cash mate. But as I said, it will be wise that you transfer your BTC to another wallet before messing up with this. Anyways, updated my answer mate.